# What is the difference between \number and \the ? No.2

Tags: macros

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%% Here is the example tex-file that illustrates use of \number and \the .   
%%                                           
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in, paperheight=0.8in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newcount\a  \newcount\b  \newcount\Sum

\a=1   \b=5  \Sum=0
\advance\Sum by \a  \multiply\Sum by \b
\advance\Sum by \a  \multiply\Sum by \b

\noindent
The Sum equals \number\Sum  \quad;\quad I used ``number''.
\par \vskip 10pt \noindent
The Sum equals \the\Sum     \quad;\quad I used ``the''.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not very good at posting tex source. The original had more separate lines. Maybe someone will give me a hint how to do it properly.

Comment: Select the code and click on the `{}` button above the editing window. How's this different from the previous question? In the answer it was explained that `\the` and `\number` before a count register give the same result.

Comment: I know. Someone said I should post a separate question, and I thought he meant an example including document class and all that. So I did. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Thanks for the tip on the source code BTW !

Comment: That comment concerned your question about using numbers in the names of variables, I think. This MWE belongs in the question you asked originally and not in a new question. (It can be confusing how this site works when you are not familiar with it!)

Comment: If we remove this one, I'll try to put the tex file into a comment with the first, since I will then have satisfied the person who preferred a full code example.

Comment: Thanks for helping out and putting the "MWE" with the first version. We can remove is one now. But I don't know how that is done. ( What does MWE stand for:   A ". . . Working Example"? )

Comment: I figured it out : It has to mean "A minimal working exampe".